# What exactly is a Desire?

Tags: four-noble-truths, desire, phenomenology

What exactly is the anatomy of a Desire and why does it have such a potent effect on our psyche and life?

Is it a ***thought*** of wanting something we don't have, but then we have so many thoughts about so many things? Is it a ***feeling*** of missing something or something being wrong in the present moment, but then we have so many other feelings? Is it a mental reaction, or ***perception*** of thought and feeling? Is it some mental energy illumined by ***consciousness***? Or is it will want?

The Buddha went as far as saying, ***taṇhā*** ("craving, desire or attachment") is the cause of suffering. I want to understand what is this as a phenomenon?

Comment: This question may be a duplicate of existing questions. Please see if the linked questions answers this question. If you feel your question is different, or if you wish to change your question, please write to me here.

Comment: Desire is whatever it is except from what you call & think about it.

Comment: Srmantically the word 'desire' has 'it desires, it desires' for designation. It desires this or that, therefore it is called desire.

Comment: If it is confusing id recommend a primer on general semantics, some popularization of 'science & sanity', eg 'Tyranny of Words'.

Comment: The linked questions covers multiple terms in Buddhism that are related to desire, which is a very broad English word - craving (*tanha*), clinging (*upadana*), desire (*chanda*), sensual desires (*kammacchanda*), sensual lust (*kamaraga*). And these questions have also discussed differences between these terms. So, I hope, they answer this question adequately too. Otherwise, you can change it to become focused, specific and unique.

Comment: Hi @ruben2020, went through the links. Thankyou for the comment.